# Prove that the set of all subsets of cardinality k of a set of cardinality n has cardinality n choose k

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients

[image]

That title is probably very compound and confusing so here's a picture.

I'm onto something here. Intuitively this makes sense. Let $A$ be a set such that $|A| = n$. If we choose the first $k$ elements of $A$, we have a subset of cardinality $k$. Then we choose a new subset but remove the first element and add on the $k+1$th element. We repeat this process up to the $n$th element and obtain $k$ subsets of order $k$.

But there are clearly more. Rather than list them all out, it would make more sense to try to think of this arbitrarily, however I guess I don't know about about binomial coefficients to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use induction on $n$ and the [recursive formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula) for binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ choices for the first element of a subset, $n-1$ choices for the second element, and so on, and $n-k+1$ choices for the $k$th element; that's
$$n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1) = \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$
choices in total. But it doesn't matter which order you chose the elements in, so you over-counted by a factor of $k!$, which is the number of rearrangements of $k$ elements.

Comment: well that is quick and easy, thank you